# can i create a mobile app on android where I issue a ticket and on opening the app , the phone starts acting like an nfc tag?

Tags: android, react-native, nfc

I want to create a mobile app where tickets are issued that can be read by an NFC reader on another phone. I want the app to act as an NFC tag that can be read by other phones. I know both android and ios phones can act as NFC readers and that ios phones cannot act as an nfc tag. However can android phones act as an nfc tag on opening my mobile app? I am using react native any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes an Android phone can act as a Type 4 NFC Tag, your App has to implement a Host Card Emulation (HCE) service.

More details are in the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce)

React Native Can call Native code, so you will have to write the HCE Service in Java/Kotlin and integrate that in to you React Native App (to my knowledge nobody as done a React Native library for this)